# When I make a div that is part of my grid layout a link, its position moves to the left. How do I prevent this?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a whole div a link. I'd like to do that rather than using `<a href>` because I'd like the whole div to be clickable and plan to add hover effects that involve the whole div.

When I add `<a>` tags around the div, however, it moves to the left. Here's the site as I'd like it to look (except the div is not yet a link): http://codepen.io/miskellaneousness/pen/QNJGZa

```
<div class="section group">

    <div class="col menu sportsm" >
    sports & entertainment
    </div>

...
</div>
```

But once I add `<a>` tags around the "sports & entertainment" menu div, it shifts to the left as seen here: http://codepen.io/miskellaneousness/pen/EKONdM

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="section group">

       <div class="col menu sportsm" >
          sports & entertainment
       </div>
</a>
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the whole area a link, do exactly that. Don't wrap your positioned div in a link. The classes control the position.

```
<a class="col menu sportsm" href="#">
sports & entertainment
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I needed.

Comment: If I might say so myself, the correct way to designate an accepted answer is to click the checkbox to the left. Welcome to StackOverflow. Make sure to take the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Move your class

Change
 a href="#" div class="col menu sportsm"

To
  a href="#" class="col menu sportsm"